# One touch SCNAction?

Tags: swift, scenekit

How can I perform an action only one time until it is completed even if the user keeps touching the object that activates the action?
Example: A Button makes a box fall by 'SCNVector3(0, -1, 0)' when it is pressed. How can I make the button not perform the action again even if the user is touching it, until the action is completed?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a state variable (boxIsFalling) when the button is pressed/box is released. Then supply a completion handler to your `runAction` call (see [`SCNActionable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnactionable)), and in the completion handler, remove the box from the scene and reset your state.